# How to calculate the size (in byte) of a subset of rows from a MySQL table using PHP with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, size, quota

First of all, I'm working on a shared hosting service with PHP 5.4.11 with PDO extension and MySQL 5.1.66 (on Debian Squeeze).

Currently I'm developing a service where users have a limited quota for storing data in the database. For now, there is only one table where userdata is stored which has to be observed regarding the quota (but that might change). All tables use the InnoDB storing engine and utf8_unicode_ci collation for text columns. Let's assume the table relevant for quota has the following columns:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| Column name  |   Type    |
+--------------+-----------+
| id           | int       |
| userId       | int       |
| created      | timestamp |
| lastModified | timestamp |
| description  | varchar   |
| content      | text      |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Now I need to calculate the size in bytes of all the rows belonging to a specific user. I have searched the documentation and googled around, but only found other people asking similar questions without getting a satisfying answer.

I know of the MySQL `LENGTH()` function, but as it is a string function, it does not return the space occupied by (fixed length) numerical and date/time fields. And if one only took string fields into account, a user might just fill up the database with empty strings never reaching his quota. I also know that there is some overhead in MySQL for each row for its description, but I do not want to include it into the calculation. (As an equivalent, I would want to calculate the real file size, not the file size on disk.)

Additionally, I do not want to rely on a specific table structure, as this might change and one would have to remember to update the function which calculates the quota.

For the lack of an existing solution, I came up with my own (see further down). But it has some drawbacks, for instance:

- It needs a list of datatypes and their respective sizes used in the table.
- It cannot accurately handle `FLOAT(p)`, `DECIMAL(M,D)`, `NUMERIC(M,D)` and `BIT(M)` datatypes (althouhg this could be implemented).
- It needs two separate queries.

So for now, this is what I've come up with:

```php
$db = new PDO(...);
$tablename = 'users';
$userId = 1;

// Make a list of type sizes in bytes - null indicates string types of
// varying size. If there is a type used in the database which is not
// listed here, an exception will be thrown.
$typeSizes = array(
    'int' => 4,
    'timestamp' => 4,
    'varchar' => null,
    'text' => null
  );

// Get datatypes used in the table.
$sql = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '
     . 'WHERE TABLE_NAME=?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $tablename);
$stmt->execute();
$colTypes = array_map('reset', array_map('reset',
                       $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));

// Iterate over the existing columns. Sum up sizes of fixed size columns to
// get a 'fixed-size-factor' for a row. Make a list of varying size columns.
$fixedSizeFactor = 0;
$varyingSizeCols = array();
foreach ($colTypes as $colName => $colType) {
  if (array_key_exists($colType, $typeSizes)) {
    if ($typeSizes[$colType] !== null) {
      $fixedSizeFactor += $typeSizes[$colType];
    } else {
      $varyingSizeCols[] = $colName;
    }
  } else {
    $msg = "Unhandled column type '$colType' - unable to calculate used "
         . 'storage. Probably the $typeSizes array needs to be updated.';
    throw new Exception($msg);
  }
}

// Get number of all records of the user and the size of his data in
// varying size columns.
$sumArgument = 0;
if (count($varyingSizeCols) > 0) {
  $sumArgument = 'LENGTH(' . implode(') + LENGTH(', $varyingSizeCols) . ')';
}
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(' . $sumArgument . ') AS size, COUNT(*) AS count FROM '
     . $tablename . ' WHERE userId=?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $userId);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Calculate used storage.
$usedStorage = $result['count'] * $fixedSizeFactor + $result['size'];
```

**My question is:** Is there a more 'native', less hackish way to do this? If not, do you have any suggestions regarding performance optimization?

Answer (score 0):

Just forget about numbers and dates, really, that's so cheap if you restrict a user because of such fields...

Use the `LENGTH` (for texts) and `OCTET_LENGTH` (for blobs) methods and that should be enough.

If you're really short on storage and you MUST divide it exactly per user, don't forget there's also log management that will increase disk space, and that these depend on the usage a user is doing from your database...

Comment: And if the OP really have to charge per byte of data, don't forget to add the overhead of the database indexes

Comment: Then how would you make shure a user doesn't insert a vast number of rows with empty texts? (Empty texts are perfectly ok for my application.) Simply have a maximum number of entries dependent on the user's quota? BTW: According to the MySQL documentation, `LENGTH()` and `OCTET_LENGTH()` are synonyms.

Comment: what kind of data are you storing in this table? According to your table definition, aside of the text column, you shouldn't care about this problem. Be realistic, if you have a storage problem there you're in trouble. Even if you have suddenly 1million of empty records what impact could it have in your db? Reconsider your infrastructure requirements maybe...